# WORDPRESS: copy or redirect custom post type to have hierarchical URL

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm using the Oshine template, which automatically creates custom post types and taxonomies.

The item i need to edit is **portfolio**

By default, portfolios have this url

```
/portfolio/portfolio-name
```

I'd need to have

```
/somepage/category/portfolio-name
```

> From the theme options I can change it, but if I add slashes, I get 404!

I tried to add a **rewrite** in functions.php but no success.

Any ideas?

I added this to the functions.php

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
function custom_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^arredo/(.*)/(.*)/?', 'portfolio/$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action("init", "custom_rewrite");
```

Comment: Did you try to flush the rewrite rules after you applied your own rewrite? Often an overseen issue, which can lead to hours of frustration. After writing a rewrite rule, go to the admin panel and save the permalinks settings page. This will flush it.

Comment: Yes. I flushed with the function and by saving into the permalinks options. Didn't work :(

Comment: I added the code I used...maybe the problem is in the regex?

Comment: @TonySamperi have a look at this question, seems your issue https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy

Comment: @Noman it could do the job. Trying now! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I couldn't manually do what I needed.

But this plugin does

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/